# When removing a link from Quick launch, I receive a "Managed Navigation" message

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, quick-launch, managed-navigation

I'm trying to remove a link from my QuickLaunch and when I click Ok, my change didn't save and I get this "In order to use Managed Navigation, you must select a navigation term set." at the top of the Navigation setting pages.  Not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose at least one of your navigation (global or current) is set to "Managed Navigation", like in this picture
[image]

You should choose a different type of navigation (Structural Navigation, for example) or select (or create and select) a term as source for navigation items (as I have done in the next picture)
[image]